# Android app crashing when trying to stream video from Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, python, android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to stream video from a raspberry pi to an android app. The server side is written in Python as below :

```
import socket
import struct
import time
import picamera

client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('192.168.0.126', 8000))
connection = client_socket.makefile('wb')

try:
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (160, 120)
        camera.framerate = 30
        time.sleep(2)
        start = time.time()
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        # Use the video-port for captures...
        for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream, 'jpeg',
                                             use_video_port=True):
            connection.write(struct.pack('<L', stream.tell()))
            connection.flush()
            stream.seek(0)
            connection.write(stream.read())
            if time.time() - start > 30:
                break
            stream.seek(0)
            stream.truncate()
    connection.write(struct.pack('<L', 0))
finally:
    connection.close()
    client_socket.close()
```

The Java class on android side is as under. I am trying to retrieve the image and display the same frame by frame in an imageview in the android app.

```
package com.example.videostreaming2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG="VS2";
    public DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    ImageView imageView;
    int len;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public class frame2video extends AsyncTask<byte[],Void, Bitmap>{

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imview);
            try{
                ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(8000);
                Socket video_receiver=serverSocket.accept();

                while(true){
                    DataInputStream dataInputStream=new DataInputStream(video_receiver.getInputStream());
                    len=Integer.parseInt(""+dataInputStream.readInt());
                    System.out.println(len);
                    byte[] buffer=new byte[len];
                    dataInputStream.readFully(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                    frame2video f2v=new frame2video();
                    f2v.execute(buffer);


                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(byte[]...buffer){

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer[0], 0, len);
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                outputStream.flush();
                return bitmap;
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I have setup port forwarding in android studio, but when I run the Java application in the emulator, and python code on the pi, I get a connection refused (ERR 111) on the pi. I have confirmed that the firewall on my mac is off. Is there another way to test the app on the emulator?
2. I suspected that the issue might be with the emulator setup, so I plugged in my android phone. Now when I run the app on my phone (connected to my mac and android studio) and run the python application on the pi, I get the following errors in studio:

```
09/29 21:43:44: Launching 'app' on Essential Products PH-1.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.videostreaming2/com.example.videostreaming2.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Waiting for process to come online...
Connected to process 5795 on device 'essential_products-ph_1-PM1LHMA812601675'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/videostreaming: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/videostreaming: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/AdrenoGLES: QUALCOMM build                   : 436c23c, I70c9d1ad86
    Build Date                       : 06/19/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.26.14.00
    Local Branch                     : mybranche992c040-71da-f106-bb16-1458d0b52ae8
    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r85-rel
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
    Build Config                     : C O 9.0.3 AArch64
I/AdrenoGLES: PFP: 0x005ff110, ME: 0x005ff066
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
```

on the python side, I still get connection refused:

```
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Is the approach to display the incoming image in imageview ok? is there an alternate approach to display the stream? I am barely getting started on android development, I may be making some dumb mistakes.

Comment: I think you might want to stream the video from the Pi over an open socket rather than send it directly to the Android device... But where are you starting the AsyncTask?

Comment: Also, `onPreExecute` is on the UI thread and I see network activity which is not permitted.  Just move that to `doInBackground`

Comment: There is an android VideoView that might be better suited to this than an ImageView